# How to make values in a list become variables and set values to them? - python

Tags: python, list, variables

I have two lists, one a list with a set of strings, and another list with a set of various values of strings or numbers.

I want to make each value from the first list to be a new variable with the same name and set its value to a value from the second list with the same position in the list.

So for example,

```
list_1 = ['Part_Number', 'Qty']
list_2 = ['RE12345', 5]

# into something like this 

Part_Number = 'RE12345'
Qty = 5
```

Comment: Are you familiar with python [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: Use a dictionary: `my_dynamic_vals = dict(zip(list_1, list_2))`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are looking something in the effect of

```py
for var,val in zip(list_1, list_2):
    locals()[var]=val
```

Not sure it is the best way, but it does what you want, if I understand your question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(list_1)):          
    globals()[list_1[i]] = list_2[i]
    print(eval(list_1[i]))
```

print statement shows the values of each variable